# MySQL query for taxonomy-meta

Tags: mysql, terms, sql, taxonomy-meta

I am working directly with MySQL, using MySQL workbench. Can you help me write a SQL query that will pull **all custom taxonomies** and their **term-meta** fields?

I have a custom taxonomy called(slug) `census-tract`

and a few custom fields attached to each:

`census-tract-income-level` `census-tract-population`

How would I go about joining the following tables

```
wp_terms
wp_termmeta
wp_term_taxonomy
```

to find `WHERE wp_termmeta.meta_key = 'census-tract-population' AND wp_termmeta.meta_key = 'census-tract-income-level'` ?

Thanks!!

Comment: do you want the taxonomies or the terms, along with the termmeta, and do you want all, or just the one you mentioned?

Comment: Just the one taxonomy I mentioned along with all of it's termmeta.

Comment: but term meta is term specific, not taxonomy specific

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I'm a little fuzzy with how the relationship/hierarchy goes. So let's try this again, SQL for .... just the one taxonomy for all of it's terms and each term's termmeta.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select t.name, t.slug, tm.meta_key, tm.meta_value
from wp_term_taxonomy AS tt
inner join wp_terms AS t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
inner join wp_termmeta AS tm ON t.term_id = tm.term_id
where tt.taxonomy = 'census-tract'
order by t.name
```